# Angular 2 text box required validation message still showing even after the value has been entered

Tags: jquery, angular

**My Requirement**

I need to hide the error message of required from the text box after the value has been entered

**What I have Did**

I have created a form in which user can add dynamic fields by clicking add button, in that there will be text box, on click of that text box am showing out a modal in which it will have the some couple of fields after the user entered the fields with value in the modal they will hit a button in the modal will be getting value and displaying it in a pre tag inside the modal footer, using jquery am getting the text from the pre tag and applying the text to the text box fields on the button clicks inside the modal footer

**Problem**

Even after the value is pasted from the pre tag using jquery still am getting the erro message how to get rid of it

this is my code for you reference

```
  <input ngControl="rules" id="rule_{{i}}" class="form-control rulez" #rules="ngForm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="text" style="width: 299px !important;">

        <div class="error" *ngIf="rules.control.touched">
            <div *ngIf="rules.control.hasError('required')">Please Select a Rule</div>
        </div>
</div>

 <pre id="preTag"></pre>
```

Jquery code to get value from the modal and applying it to the same text box when the modal popped up by onclick

```
var idz, valz;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).delegate('#getRuleStr', 'click', function () {
        console.log("hey"+idz);
        $('#'+idz).val($('#preTag').text());
    });
    $(document).delegate('.rulez', 'click', function () {
        idz = this.id;
        valz = $('#' + idz).val();
        console.log("inn" + valz);

            $('#builder').queryBuilder('reset');
            $('#resultRule').addClass('hide').find('pre').empty();

    });
});
```

Please help me resolve this issue

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @JamesVo yep do you have it ?..

Comment: Yeah, can you post your solution answer, It's better to use others.

Comment: you too having the same problem or you are having the solution

Comment: In my case i'm updating value using jquery, but it's not set to model, So error is showing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477778/how-to-set-input-value-and-updating-model-value-using-jquery-in-angularjs2

Comment: @JamesVo ma also trying hard to find the solution for this still can't able to get it if you would find it plz paste the solution else if I will do the same

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you need to emit the `change` event on the input after modifying the value to make Angular2 Forms update its state.

In Angular2 it's usually better to update the model and bind to it from the view to get the view updated to reflect the model by Angular2, instead of messing with the DOM directly using jQuery.

Comment: Zochbauer could you just provide a sample code or link to achieve what you have mentioned please

Comment: Sorry, I don't know jQuery and your example doesn't make much sense to me. Emitting an event shouldn't be too hard using jQuery though.

Comment: Zochbauer how can I Update Angular control group with jQuery value in angular 2 any idea plz help me in this regards