# How to set input value and updating model value using jquery in Angularjs2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular

I'm planning to upgrade angularjs 1 application to angularjs2.
Here issue is how to set input value and update model value using jquery in angualrjs2.

Here is my code:

```
export class AppComponent {
  public user: User = {
    name: 'John',
    address: {
      address1: '11, High Street'
    }
  }
  ngOnInit() {
      console.log("User name ::"+this.user.name)
      console.log('ngOnInit')
      $('#postcode').val('123456');
  }
  public save(form: IUser, isValid: boolean) {
    console.log(form, isValid);
  }
}
```

plunkr code : http://plnkr.co/edit/BGYTpytD7kGMmRODE796

Comment: In Angular2 you usually update the model and let Angular update the view according to the model. See also this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372856/angular-2-text-box-required-validation-message-still-showing-even-after-the-valu/38433340#38433340

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer yeah, Our application have some jquery dependencies. This is sample scenario code i placed here.

Answer (score 0):

Angular render model data internally, you will need to remove data binding in the `<input>` tag, if you have to use Jquery:
Change

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="postcode"
          [(ngModel)]="user.address.postcode" id="postcode">
```

to

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="postcode"
         id="postcode">
```

Check demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/RVSwYjaLIPE4Uv4s75oD?p=info

The other better way will be just change the model:

```
public user: User = {
name: 'John',
address: {
  address1: '11, High Street',
  postcode : "N14 46T"   // <--------Add postcode property
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joey, But here we need update value from jquery and then get from model.

Comment: When you binding a model, there is no way to change it by Jquery, its against Angular internal view rendering process.